# "Must declare the scalar variable" error when executing a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have tried to make a procedure to insert a price:

```
create procedure prInsertPrice
@NuggetID varchar(5),
@Unit_Price money,
@Start_Date datetime,
@End_Date datetime
as
begin
DECLARE @date AS DATETIME
SET @date = GETDATE()
    if
        (
        (@NuggetID like 'N[0-9][0-9]')
        and
        (@Unit_Price is not null)
        and
        (@Start_Date is not null)
        )
    begin
        print 'Insert Success'
        insert NuggetPrice (NuggetId, Unit_Price, Start_Date, End_Date)
        values (@NuggetID, @Unit_Price, @Start_Date, @End_Date)
    end
    else
    begin
        print 'Failed to insert'
    end
end
```

When I execute the procedure it's fine, but when I run the procedure like this:

```
EXEC prInsertPrice 'N01', 20000, @date, null
```

I get the error message:

> Must declare the scalar variable @date.

Why is this and how can I correct the problem?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you have to add `DECLARE @date datetime` and set this variable in the same batch as you run the exec.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to know what you are trying to do, before we can give an acceptable answer. so... *WHAT WAS YOUR INTENTION HERE?* what  were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I am trying to create a procedure of which will be able to do an insert based on the contents of the procedur. Well here I have a problem with variable declaration, which I was required to use `getdate()` function  to get the current time when the exec the proc. sorry for bad english, isn't my native language.

Answer (score 5):

The @date in the exec statement is different then the one in the stored proc.

You should do something like:

```
DECLARE @date AS DATETIME
SET @date = GETDATE()
EXEC prInsertPrice 'N01', 20000, @date, null
```

Answer (score 3):

When you run:

```
EXEC prInsertPrice 'N01', 20000, @date, null
```

You are passing the variable `@date` as the third parameter to your stored procedure, as `@Start_Date`. This is entirely separate from the `@date` variable which you have declared **inside** the stored procedure itself, which gets declared and initialised *after* the procedure has been called, as it executes.

If you have not initialised the `@date` variable which is being passed as a parameter to the stored procedure before calling the stored procedure, then you will get the error you have described.

So, you need to declare and initialise this variable first:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2017-01-01' -- You can whatever date value you require here
EXEC prInsertPrice 'N01', 20000, @date, null
```

This should prevent the error.

Note: You can also separate the declaration and initialisation of the `@date` variable if you would prefer:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = '2017-01-01'
```

In addressing your underlying problem though or preventing bad data being inserted into your `NuggetPrice` table though, I would agree with [Prdp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3349551/prdp)'s suggestion of adding a `CHECK` Constraint to the table, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE NuggetPrice
  ADD CONSTRAINT CK_NuggetPrice CHECK (NuggetID LIKE 'N[0-9][0-9]' 
                                       AND Unit_Price IS NOT NULL 
                                       AND Start_Date IS NOT NULL)
```

This would also prevent anyone from inserting records which do not agree with the logic specified.

Answer (score 1):

Already other two answers gave enough information on the reason for error so am not going to talk about it. Here is different approach to solve the data validation

Instead of creating a `Stored Procedure` to restrict inserting bad data into table, I would suggest you to create a `Check constraint` to do this

```
ALTER TABLE NuggetPrice
  ADD CONSTRAINT CK_NuggetPrice CHECK (NuggetID LIKE 'N[0-9][0-9]' AND Unit_Price IS NOT NULL AND Start_Date IS NOT NULL)
```

This will make sure nobody inserts bad data in `NuggetPrice`

Comment: While I agree this might be a better solution to the underlying problem of data validation, this answer doesn't help the OP understand *why* he was getting the specific error in his question.

Comment: @3N1GM4 Thats because already you guys answered on the reason for error

Comment: fair enough, I understand. Would you object to me including your suggestion in my answer to improve it? Equally, feel free to take my answer and work it into yours if you'd prefer.

Comment: @3N1GM4 - Not at all.. please improve your answer